# Volume bounded by two cylinders

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I'm confused by these "surfaces". I know how to find volume when curve rotates around $Ox$ or $Oy$ line, but I don't know what to do with surfaces. I need to find volume bounded by surfaces
$$
\left(x \over a\right)^{2} + \left(y \over b\right)^{2} = 1\qquad\mbox{and}\qquad
\left(x \over a\right)^{2} + \left(z \over c\right)^{2} =1\,,\qquad\qquad
a,\,b,\,c\ >\ 0
$$
Also, I'm not allowed to use multiple integrals. So, could someone provide me a hint, or maybe if there is any formula.

Comment: While this question is unsolved for general elliptical axes lengths, I'd like to make a link to the [related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799049). Also see the [meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868).

Answer (score 1):

You're being asked to compute the volume of the intersection of two cylinders, apparently called the [Steinmetz solid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinmetz_solid).  The Wikipedia entry gives the answer $16r^3/3$ when $a=b=c=r$ and shows how to get it without doing multiple integrals.  A simple scaling argument gives the answer $16abc/3$ for your problem.